# PHP sessions and header redirecting

Tags: php, session, redirect, authentication, header

I am having issues mainly with re-directing the user. I have a simple login system (which works as expected). This code checks the login status of the user:

```
if (!(isset($_SESSION['logged']) && $_SESSION['logged'] != '')) {
   header("Location: ./login_page.php");
   echo"logged";
}
```

The check is working, because when a user is not logged in it displays the words "logged". The only issue is it does not re-direct the user to the login page, making the application security effectively useless.

In summery, the login check works fine, but the header redirect does not.

Comment: It's either header or echo, can't have both. Add `exit;` after header and check for errors. You may be outputting before header => `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I've just found the issue, the code was situated under the <!doctype html> tags. I've done this so many times before It's unreal.

Comment: I always loved a happy ending ;)